# Target HTML element using 2 data- attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having problems targeting a div that has 2 data- element. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
    <button data-button="inventoryb" data-name="overview" style="width:120px">Overview</button>
    <button data-button="inventoryb" data-name="schedule" style="width:120px">Schedule</button>
    <button data-button="inventoryb" data-name="plan" style="width:120px">Inventory Plan</button>
    <button data-button="inventoryb" data-name="atl" style="width:120px">Inventory ATL</button>
```

Could you please help me target one button using JQuery. I've tried this

```
$("button[data-button='inventoryb']").find("button[data-name='overview']").click();
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Thank you in advance, and sorry if I post a duplicate question. I couldn't find a similar problem to mine.

Edit: I would like to have both data- attributes in the search, as in another code of mine, there is a similar structure:

```
    <button data-button="taskb" data-name="overview" style="width:120px">Overview</button>
    <button data-button="taskb" data-name="list" style="width:120px">Schedule</button>
```

so just search by data-name is not enough to target the right button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the attribute name and value inside [***attr()***](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). It'll work.

***Method 1 :***

```
$("button[data-button='inventoryb']").attr("data-name","overview").click();
```

Or, you can also go with the nested call to [***attr()***](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

***Method 2 :***

```
$("button").attr("data-button", "inventoryb").attr("data-name","overview").click();
```

***Note :*** Now there's an issue. According to my code the click event will be fired for all the buttons having

> *data-button='inventoryb' **or** data-name='overview'*

But what if you want to fire the click event only for the buttons having both

> *data-button='inventoryb' **and** data-name='overview'*

Then I suggest to go with the nested selector option which has already been answered by many. Still giving a demo here,

```
$("button[data-button='inventoryb'][data-name='schedule']").click();
```

[***working fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/cstynax6/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$("button[data-button=inventoryb][data-name=overview]").click()
```

Comment: thank you, that's what I'm looking for. I'll accept the answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this if you want to locate button which is having `data-button` attribute and `data-name` is different,

```
$( "button[data-button][data-name='list']" ).click();
```

Note : this is just suggestion..

---

you can do like this use multiple attribute selector

```
$( "button[data-button='inventoryb'][data-name='overview']" ).click();
```

Read more about this : [Multiple Attribute Selector [name="value"][name2="value2"]](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

`$("button [data-button='inventoryb'][data-name='overview']").click();`